# If $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$ so $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{(1-ab)^2}\leq\frac{27}{4}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$. Prove that:
>   $$\frac{1}{(1-ab)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-ac)^2}+\frac{1}{(1-bc)^2}\leq\frac{27}{4}$$

This inequality is stronger than $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1-ab}\leq\frac{9}{2}$ with the same condition,

which we can prove by AM-GM and C-S:
$$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{1-ab}=3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{1}{1-ab}-1\right)=3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{ab}{1-ab}\leq$$
$$\leq3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{2(2a^2+2b^2+2c^2-2ab)}\leq3+\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{(a+b)^2}{2(a^2+b^2+2c^2)}\leq$$
$$\leq3+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2}{a^2+c^2}+\frac{b^2}{b^2+c^2}\right)=\frac{9}{2},$$
but for the starting inequality this idea does not work.

By the way, I have a proof of the following inequality.

Let $a$, $b$ and $c$ be real numbers such that $a^2+b^2+c^2=3$. Prove that:
 $$\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{(4-ab)^2}\leq\frac{1}{3}$$
(we can prove it by SOS and uvw).

This inequality is weaker and it not comforting.

We can assume of course that all variables are non-negatives.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Let $x = \dfrac{1}{1-ab}$, $y = \dfrac{1}{1-bc}$, $z = \dfrac{1}{1-ac}$.

We have proven that

$$x + y + z \leq \dfrac{9}{2}.$$

Therefore, $x + y + z = \dfrac{9}{2} - \varepsilon$ for some $0 \leq \varepsilon \leq \dfrac{9}{2}$. If we assume that $x,y,z \geq 0$, which we can, we can square both sides and obtain

$$(x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + (2xy + 2yz + 2xz) = \bigg{(} \dfrac{9}{2} - \varepsilon \bigg{)}^2 \leq \dfrac{81}{4}$$

We can say that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq \dfrac{81}{4} - 2(xy + yz + xz)$. We now seek to minimize $xy + yz + xz$ in order to maximize the upper bound.

We are given that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 1$, and since $xy + yz + xz$ is a symmetric polynomial in $x,y,z$, we should seek $x=y=z>0$ as our minimum, which can be shown the be the case using very straightforward techniques from calculus (Second derivative test should suffice, proving the minimum for $a,b,c$ suffices). We find that $x=y=z$ when $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$, so that $x=y=z=\dfrac{1}{1-1/3}=\dfrac{3}{2}$. We can then say that

$$xy + yz + xz \geq 3*(3/2)^2 = 3*(9/4) = 27/4$$

Therefore,

$$x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \leq \dfrac{81}{4} - 2*\dfrac{27}{4} = \dfrac{81}{4} - \dfrac{54}{4} = \dfrac{27}{4}$$

Comment: I don't see how you obtain the final, desired inequality.  You seem to just assert it.

Comment: This comes from the fact that the function $f(x) = x^2$ is monotonically increasing on $\mathbb{R}^+$. By that I mean that for positive reals $x,h$, $x^2 < (x+h)^2$. Since $\dfrac{9}{2} \geq \dfrac{9}{2} - \varepsilon$ and since both are positive, $\bigg{(} \dfrac{9}{2} \bigg{)}^2 \geq \bigg{(} \dfrac{9}{2} - \varepsilon \bigg{)}^2$. Does that answer your question?

Comment: $\frac{9}{2}=81/4$, so we cannot say $(\frac{9}{2} - \varepsilon)^2\le 27/4$

Comment: I wasn't thinking, my fault. I will see if I can correct my approach.

Comment: @didgogns I fixed the proof. Needed some calculus to make it work, but nothing difficult.

Comment: @Will Craig   We can not say that $xy+yz+zx \ge \frac{27}{4}$. For example, when $a=1, b=0, c=0$, we have $x=y=z=1$ and $xy+yz+zx = 3 < \frac{27}{4}$.

Answer (score 0):

The Buffalo Way works. (I think that Michael Rozenberg knew this.)

We only need to prove the case $a, b, c > 0$.

After homogenization and clearing the denominators, it suffices to prove that 
$f(a, b,c)\ge 0$ where $f(a,b,c)$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $12$.

Due to symmetry, assume that $c\le b\le a$. Let $c = 1, \ b = 1+s, \ a = 1+s+t; \ s,t\ge 0$.
Then $f(1+s+t, 1+s, 1)$ is a polynomial in $s, t$ with non-negative coefficients. We are done.

Answer (score 0):

*My second proof*:

**Fact 1**: $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} \le \frac{729}{40}x^4 + \frac{243}{40}x^2 + \frac{27}{20}$ for all $x \le 1/2$.
(*Note*: $\frac{729}{40}x^4 + \frac{243}{40}x^2 + \frac{27}{20} - \frac{1}{(1-x)^2}
= \frac{(81x^4 - 108x^3 + 27x^2 - 24x + 14)(1-3x)^2}{40(1-x)^2} \ge 0$.)

By Fact 1, using $ab, bc, ca \le 1/2$, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{729}{40}((ab)^4 + (bc)^4 + (ca)^4) + \frac{243}{40}((ab)^2 + (bc)^2 + (ca)^2) + \frac{81}{20}
\le \frac{27}{4}$$
or
$$27(a^4b^4 + b^4c^4 + c^4a^4) + 9(a^2b^2 + b^2c^2 + c^2a^2) \le 4.$$

Letting $x = a^2, y = b^2$ and $z = c^2$,
it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z \ge 0$ with $x + y + z = 1$,
$$27(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) + 9(xy + yz + zx) \le 4. \tag{1}$$

WLOG, assume that $z = \min(x, y, z)$. Then $z \le 1/3$.

We have
\begin{align*}
 &27(x^2y^2 + y^2z^2 + z^2x^2) + 9(xy + yz + zx)\\
 ={}& 27(xy)^2 + xy(9 - 54z^2) + 27(x + y)^2z^2 + 9(x + y)z\\[6pt]
 \le{}& 27\left(\frac{(x + y)^2}{4}\right)^2 + \frac{(x + y)^2}{4}\cdot (9 - 54z^2) + 27(x + y)^2z^2 + 9(x + y)z\\
 ={}& 4 - \frac{1}{16}(-27z^2 + 42z + 1)(1 - 3z)^2 \\
 \le{}& 4
\end{align*}
where we use $xy \le (x + y)^2/4$ and $9 - 54z^2 > 0$.

We are done.